# updating headers of every file in an amazon s3 bucket

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3

I have a large number of files that have incorrect mimetypes in a bucket, as well as no expires set.

How can I change them all?

I'm using Knox:

https://github.com/LearnBoost/knox

I'm trying to iterate over it. How do I get a list of all files in a folder?

When I do this

```
  client.get('/folder').on('response', function(res){
    console.log(res)
    res.on('data', function(chunk){
      console.log(chunk);
    });
  }).end();
```

I see osmething about an xml file, how do I access it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like the library you have chosen does not have any native support for listing buckets. You will need to construct the list requests and parse the XML yourself - documentation for the underlying REST API can be found in the [S3 API documentation.](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/index.html?RESTBucketGET.html)

Once you get a list of objects, you can use the [S3 copy request functionality](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectCOPY.html) to update metadata. Just [apply this patch](https://github.com/maxpert/knox/commit/94b7845fcc2934fbfcfd99be9fed7e2875d5ab06), then pass `x-amz-metadata-directive: REPLACE` as a header to a copy request specifying the same key as source and destination (the source must specify the bucket as well!), plus any other headers you want to set.

Comment: I'm not entirely familiar with your library, so it'd help to see some error output from that...

Comment: Also, what's with the `Vary: accept-encoding`? S3 objects are static, so they don't, in fact, vary on the accept-encoding header. Removing that will improve caching performance.